# Vim, context-sensitive comment/uncomment behavior

Tags: vim, php

I edit a lot of PHP code with Vim, and I've run into a snag with some macros in my `.vimrc`.

I currently use these two macros to comment/uncomment in C-style

```
"c-style (//) comment (press the [.] key)
au FileType php vnoremap . :s/^\(\s*\)\(.\+\)$/\1\/\/\2/<CR>:noh<CR>gv
"c-style (//) uncomment (press the [,] key)
au FileType php vnoremap , :s/^\(\s*\)\/\//\1/<CR>:noh<CR>gv
```

And these two to comment/uncomment in HTML-style

```
"html-style (<!-- -->) comment (press the [.] key)
au FileType html vnoremap . :s/^\(\s*\)\(.\+\)$/\1<!-- \2 -->/g<CR>:noh<CR>gv
"html-style (<!-- -->) uncomment (press the [,] key)
au FileType html vnoremap , :s/^\(\s*\)<!-- \(.*\) -->/\1\2/g<CR>:noh<CR>gv
```

These macros work fine when applied to their intended file-type, but since there is often HTML embedded inside a PHP file, the PHP commenting style is useless.

Is there a way for Vim to detect if it's working on a chunk of HTML code inside a PHP file, and then apply the correct commenting behaviour?

Edit: I know that I can manually set the filetype, and that there are plugins available for this, I was looking to learn more about writing better macros.

Comment: So you're sort of looking for a [Vim analog to Emacs's MMM mode](http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/2009/11/reader-question-mmm-mode.html), which leads to http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want there is really no way to get around writing a function and mapping it your preferred keys.

To get started `:echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")` will print the name of the highlight group for the current word under the cursor.

You can use that information to determine which comment style to use.

A rough example to get you started:

```
function! s:MyComment () range
    for i in range(a:firstline, a:lastline)
        exe "normal " . i . "gg"
        normal ^
        let stuff = synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")
        if strpart(stuff, 0, 4) == "html"
            normal I<!-- 
            normal A -->
        else
            normal I//
        endif
    endfor
endfunction
vmap <silent> . :call <SID>MyComment()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you can accept to choose manually which type of comment you want to use, I would recommend this [tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Easy_%28un%29commenting_out_of_source_code).

You would have 4 combinations to remember:

```
C-style:
,* comment  
,c uncomment

HTML style: 
,< comment 
,d uncomment
```